# Pubspec.yaml what this file does in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, flutter-pub

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite: any
  path_provider: any
  intl: ^0.15.7
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

What things are written in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

The version of your application or package.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
```

Your application or package claims to support Dart SDK within this version range

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Your application or package depends on the `flutter` package which can be found in the SDK

```
  sqflite: any
```

Your application or package depends on the package `sqflite` from https://pub.dartlang.org with no specific version constraint.

```
  path_provider: any
  intl: ^0.15.7
```

Your application or package depends on the package `intl` from https://pub.dartlang.org on any version `0.15.7` or later but before `0.16.0`.

```
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

The `^` changes the meaning for versions `1.0.0` and later.

`^0.15.7` means `>=0.15.7 <0.16.0`
`^1.15.7` means `>=1.15.7 <2.0.0`

because for versions < `1.0.0` breaking changes are indicated by incrementing the middle number, while for >= `1.0.0` breaking changes are indicated by incrementing the first part of the version.

Answer (score 2):

It is responsible for handling of importing images/fonts/third party packages which you want to include in your project.

Comment: Thanks can You Explain in detail

Comment: have you used android studio?

Comment: ok so you must know about android manifest file.. pubspec.yaml is same as android manifest..as sample as that :)

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here on the Flutter site](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab#step-2-use-an-external-package):

> The pubspec file manages the assets and dependencies for a Flutter app.

More info can be found [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/get-started).

Answer (score 0):

To briefly explain, this file written in the [YAML](https://yaml.org/) language, allows you to manage the pub packages you want to use in your flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

From the dart page :

Every pub package needs some metadata so it can specify its dependencies. Pub packages that are shared with others also need to provide some other information so users can discover them. All of this metadata goes in the package’s pubspec: a file named pubspec.yaml that’s written in the YAML language.

So you will find all the required dependencies / fonts and images sources /sdk version  in the pubspec.yaml